# Azimuth values changing when changing pitch

Tags: android, orientation, sensors

I need the device's azimuth and roll values for an augmented reality app I'm working on. I'm getting the rotation matrix - from `getRotationMatrix` - using the accelerometer and the magnetic field. Since this is an AR app, I need to render objects that wouldn't change their positions in the real world (when seen through the camera) when the device is moved.

The problem is, when physically rolling the device (in attempts to observe the variations in the pitch values), I can observe changes in the azimuth orientation values, even though that should remain stable. Moreover, the azimuth strays off only when the pitch is changing, and returns back to its original value when the rolling is stopped.
So to clarify, as I start the roll, the azimuth starts changing as well, and when the roll stops, the azimuth slowly returns back to the correct value. I can't figure out why the azimuth is behaving so.

Here is the code that gets the sensor data and calculates the rotation matrix.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    switch (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        accel = lowPass(sensorEvent.values.clone(), accel);
        break;

    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
        magnet = lowPass(sensorEvent.values.clone(), magnet);
        break;
    }

    if (accel == null || magnet == null)
        return;

    if (!SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accel, magnet))
        return;
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
            SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, outRotationMatrix); // Remapping because the device is held in landscape.
    SensorManager.getOrientation(outRotationMatrix, orientationValues);

    currentOrientation = (float) (Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[0]) + this.getDeclination()); //Azimuth; (Degrees);
    eyeLevelInclination = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[1]); //Pitch; (Degrees); down is 90 , up is -90.
    deviceOrientation = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[2]);

    sendSensorBroadcast(); 
}
```

So in the code above, `currentOrientation` (responsible for horizontally stabilizing the rendered AR objects) changes during device roll, when only `eyeLevelInclination` should be changing (responsible for vertically stabilizing the rendered AR object).
I'm also using a low pass filter to stabilize the sensor data. Although I dont believe this is responsible for the azimuth variations, I'm putting its code here regardless-

```
static final float ALPHA = 0.15f;

/**
 * @see Adapted from http://blog.thomnichols.org/2011/08/smoothing-sensor-data-with-a-low-pass-filter
 */
protected float[] lowPass( float[] input, float[] output ) {
    if ( output == null ) return input;

    for ( int i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
        output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Apologies if the question isn't very clear. It's a bit hard to explain the problem.

**Edit**: I've tried using raw values, instead of going through a low pass filter and the azimuth still changes. I notice that the rendered object goes along a diagonal when changing the pitch, when it should only be going vertically up or down. It moves diagonally as the azimuth and the pitch both are changing when I physically change the device's pitch, causing the diagonal movement. Maybe there's something wrong with my axis?

Comment: I just kinda asked a similar question - Hope an answer to your question or to mine could help both of us :-) See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792048/sensormanager-getrotationmatrix-strange-behavior)

Comment: @gilonm That is indeed pretty similar. I'll keep an eye on it. Thank you.

Comment: Same here, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing how I was able to find no solution to this issue, I started to look at other possible ways of handling the sensors.
I found out a much better way of handling the sensor data, that eliminated not only the azimuth swaying, but also the need to have a filter to smooth the sensor values:
Instead of using `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` values to calculate the rotation matrix, I used the `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` sensor. Then, got the rotation matrix from this, and as done earlier, got the orientation array from it.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    switch (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()) {

    case Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:
        rotationMatrix=new float[16];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, sensorEvent.values);
    }

    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
            SensorManager.AXIS_Z, outRotationMatrix);   // Remap coordinate System to compensate for the landscape position of device
    SensorManager.getOrientation(outRotationMatrix, orientationValues);

    currentOrientation = (float) (Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[0]) + this.getDeclination()); //Azimuth; (Degrees);
    eyeLevelInclination = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[1]); //Pitch; (Degrees); down is 90 , up is -90.
    deviceOrientation = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[2]); // Roll;

    sendSensorBroadcast();  // Let other classes know of update to sensor data.
```

As you can see in my question above, I was using a low pass filter to smooth the azimuth and pitch values, but this wasn't needed anymore, as the values were pretty smooth without any filtering. Plus, the azimuth swaying is almost gone now. I say almost because you can maybe still see a bit of it happening, but its barely noticeable, maybe about half a degree.

I was stuck with this problem for quite some time, hopefully this will help someone else too.

Comment: Hi @Urban, Say my app is in Portrait orientation - if so I understand that I don't need the `SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem` part?

Comment: Hi @gilonm, yes I think you won't need it in that case. Run the code on the device and rotate along one axis. If the sensor data matches the expected output of only the axis you moved along, then you know your coordinate system is fine.

Comment: Hi again... where is `getDeclination()` declared? I have left it out for now but nothing works... still looking into it...

Comment: Hey @gilonm, here is [declination](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/GeomagneticField.html#getDeclination()). Although this shouldn't make a big difference, and I doubt fixing this would help much. Maybe something else is wrong, but anyways, try adding this.

Comment: I Got it, Works perfectly! A huge thank you for all your help! BTW it was not working before seeing I forgot to add the new vector sensor in the `onResume()`... Again - Thanks!

Comment: The case TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR is never received. Is there a reason why?

Comment: TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR  may not be available on your device.  `SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
            SensorManager.AXIS_Z, outRotationMatrix); ` remaps devices xyz coordinates to wolrd coordinates for devices in landscape or portrait orientations if the screen is pointing at you.(AR applications) If the screen is lying flat on surface(compass) you need to look for other axis changes.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't matter what orientation the device is held (Portrait or Landscape and their variations), if you are interested in the back camera direction then you have to call

```
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X,
        SensorManager.AXIS_Z, outRotationMatrix);
```

The above call together with `getOrientation` gives the direction of the back camera with respect to magnetic north independent of the orientation of the device (Portrait, Landscape or anything in between).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed that, although that wasn't creating the issue. The azimuth value still strays off (and returns back) when I'm changing the pitch of the phone (In addition to the pitch values of course)

Comment: You should use TYPE_GRAVITY instead of TYPE_ACCELEROMETER if possible. There will be changed in the azimuth as the pitch changes because the gravity parameter in the getRotationMatrix is not a very good approximation of gravity when the device is rotated. In one of my answer about this kind of sensor, I stated that there are two essential assumptions that allows one to find the rotation matrix. One of them is that the gravity parameter in the getRotationMatrix is a vector lying in the world gravity direction. This is not the case when the device is moving.

Comment: Also you should not filter the magnetic field. The low pass filtering of the accelerometer values is to isolate the gravity component of the accelerometer vector. I do not know any reason why one should filter magnetic field. After all if there is a strong magnetic interference at one spot and when you move away from that spot why do you still want the interference to continue to influence the magnetic field value?

Comment: Pretty much every tutorial on the web uses Type_Accelerometer instead of gravity. Now, I don't dont much about their working, so I'm not sure which is correct. Regardless, I tried out using Gravity instead of accelerometer. The azimuth did stray off again (as the pitch changed), however this time it did not return back when the pitch stopped changing. The azimuth stayed at its value when the pitch stopped. As the pitch angle increased, the azimuth also increased in value. I'm honestly baffled by how not many people have witnessed this before.

Comment: Well, I found out a solution to my problem. But since anyways I can't get the bounty for my own answer, I thought I'll give that to you, since you at least tried to help, and took the time to go through my detailed question.

Comment: Why does it not need another remapping when you change from portrait to landscape if device is not flat on a surface?

`X axis = SensorManager.AXIS_X
Y axis = SensorManager.AXIS_Z`

If it's lying flat on a surface, you need to remap axes such as
Portrait
`X axis = SensorManager.AXIS_X
Y axis = SensorManager.AXIS_Z`

Landscape
`X axis = SensorManager.AXIS_Y
Y axis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X`

Comment: When you remap as above, then the value[0] of getOrientation is the direction of the phone z direction, that is the direction opposite to the screen. If you rotate the phone from portrait to landscape the direction of z still points to the same direction. The screen still points to the same direction whether the phone is in portrait or landscape.